# azure web service app date format issue

Tags: sql-server, azure-web-app-service, date-format

Im developing an app thats hosted up in Azure.  On my development machine when i edit and save dates (UK format - saving to local sql server 2012) theres no problem.  When I deploy the same code base to Azure (same database structure & sql server version - db hosted in VM in Azure) Im getting an error

'the value 23/01/2014' is not valid for contract date

has anyone else experienced anything like this and could give me some pointers ?
Ive set the os on the VM machine to be uk region and the underlying dates in the tables both locally and remotely are exactly the same format.  Is there anything obvious I could be missing ?

Comment: You could use the [ISO 8601](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-transact-sql) format YYYY-MM-DD and then use the [FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql) function for displaying purposes. I know this likely is something you are trying to avoid, but it avoids the error entirely.

Answer (score 0):

> the value 23/01/2014' is not valid for contract date

Please run `dbcc useroptions` to check the language and dateformat. And by default, the date format for SQL server is in U.S. date format MM/DD/YY, unless a localized version of SQL Server has been installed.

You could try to use the international format `YYYYMMDD` for sending the datetime data to SQL Server or pass the date in date format being used on the SQL Server.

Comment: the problem isnt with the DB Ive checked and its not being hit, its client side validation thats causing it. But it validates UK date format fine on my dev machine, its only after deploying to Azure that it thinks it US format date.  I using the globalize.js validator and its set to en-GB.  Does my Azure environment need to be localised to UK ?  Its hosted in western Europe

Comment: ``its client side validation thats causing it`` do you mean that the error is returned by client side jquery validator, not SQL database?